# Como clicar em tags HTML não clicáveis? Via console

Tags: javascript, html, console, html-tags

Bom pessoal estou com uma duvida, eu gostaria de clicar em elementos HTML não clicáveis, como por exemplo

Eu sei que com o seguinte código podemos clicar em um botão

**sabendo que estou trabalhando via console no navegador**

```
document.element.click()
```

Sendo que

```
element = <a>
```

Agora como eu faria se caso fosse uma div ou outra tag HTML?

Comment: Talvez possa ajudar, Relacionada: [Como fazer um trigger para um evento SEM jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243882/3774)

Comment: Relacionada: [Como criar e usar eventos personalizados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/331560/3774)

Comment: E por que você gostaria de clicar em uma `div`, que não tem nenhuma ação ao clique? O que você espera que esse _click_ "artificial" faça?

Comment: Então é por curiosidade pois estou em uma pagina e percebi que o campo só fica editavel quando eu clico no componente, mas percebi que é resposta é trabalhar com eventos e não manipulando o DOM como eu estava tentando fazer. @LuizFelipe.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo links @IcaroMartins acho que com eles vou conseguir oque quero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grande questão é que você consegue adicionar event listener para um 'click' em qualquer elemento html.

No seu caso, uma div, é só adicionar a function handler do evento:

```
const divElement = document.querySelector('#idDaDiv');
divElement.addEventListener('click', () => alert('clicou'));
```

E então, quando quiser, **disparar o evento** como você mesmo mencionou acima:

```
//...
divElement.click();
```

Ou **disparar o evento** usando alguma das abordagens das outras respostas.